# How to send silent premium SMS on Android device

Tags: android, sms

I am writing a care application for the mobile devices of my company. 
In my app, I must send an activation SMS to 8177.

It is intended that the first time a user turns on their android device, the care activation SMS will be automatically sent, and I don't want to let user know that (silent sending).

But in my Android 4.x.x device, when I attempt to send the activation SMS, a confirmation dialog is displayed to ask the user to send the SMS or not.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since an SMS always costs a user some of his/her bundle or money, this confirmation cannot be circumnavigated by app code ([from Android 4.2 and higher](http://www.androidauthority.com/android-4-2-potential-security-features-unveiled-selinux-vpn-lockdown-premium-sms-confirmation-123785/)).

Comment: But this SMS is use to activate the care information, It's necessary.

Comment: Then something else have to be thought of. It is simply impossible to do this on unrooted devices from Android 4.2 and up.

Comment: I'll contact the Chipset API to do that function. Thanks!